# How does it start the device in tensorflow？

Tags: tensorflow, device

How does it start the device in tensorflow？And where can I found the details  in source code.  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: What is "it"? and which "device" are you referring to? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to know the how the tensorflow calls the device(cpu).

Comment: I want to know the how the tensorflow calls the device(cpu).                           How does tensorflow distributes the task to the device ?                                      It's said that why device(cpu) can be detected automatically  in tensorflow?

Comment: isn't this a simple call to sysinfo and then run a task on it?

Comment: but  why device(cpu) can be detected automatically in tensorflow? If I plan to add a new device,and how to assign the task to my device? Does it need some interface between the device and tensorflow?

Comment: You can manually assign tasks - see answer

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a task to a device like this:

```
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)

Comment: could you point out the position of source code in tensorflow?

Comment: it is buried in here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/graph
but since I still don't get what you're looking for... please see yourself

Comment: I means that when I add a new device in tensorflow,if I registered it in device factory,do I call the device just like:tf.device('/cpu:0'):